# rectangle without border

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, draw2d

In draw2d,How can I draw a figure without having any border?
How to implements the CustomBorder for rectangles to remove the border?
I know if we implement a class which extends Border, and in the paint method what should I do to remove the border?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figures don't have a border unless you explicitly set one by calling `setBorder(..)`. If you just want a blank figure that doesn't draw anything, then `new Figure()` will give you just that. There's no need to implement any custom borders or figures. If you are using a `Rectangle` then that's exactly what you will get: a rectangle; which is what you probably confused for a border.

Comment: Yaa true. But If a draw a figure and try to show it in the the canvas it is giving me a blank figure. that means it is not visible. I tried to set the background  to see whether can make it visible or not.But I could not see. So I assumed that Figures are basically a kind of container to contain other shapes. Is that correct? Please make me understand. That is the reason I approached with the custom rectangle without having any border.

Comment: With "figure.setOpaque(true)" the `Figure` will draw its background color.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the border with `figure.setBorder(null);` or you can put it in the constructor:

```
public static  class BorderlessFigure extends Figure {
    public BorderlessFigure() {
        ToolbarLayout layout = new ToolbarLayout();
        setLayoutManager(layout);   
        setBorder(null);
        add(new Label("test"));  
    }
}
```

If you want a Border that does not paint anything you can extend `org.eclipse.draw2d.AbstractBorder`:

```
public class NoBorderBorder extends AbstractBorder {
    @Override
    public void paint(IFigure f, Graphics g, Insets i) { }

    @Override
    public Insets getInsets(IFigure f) {
        return new Insets(0);
    }
}
```

I don't know why would you do that though.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the suggestion. I tried in that way before I posted here. But did not work at all. Then I tried to use custom figure which extends Rectangle figure. Then I could draw rectangle without having any border.